# How to merge 2 pictureboxes with a fixed location

Tags: vb.net, winforms, screenshot

I had 2 picture boxes and I just wanted to export them as 1 image . 
All I need is to export them in their state, not to create a .bmp. I tried to do it as a screenshot for the form , but the problem is sometimes the picture is bigger than the form, the screenshot only takes the part visible for the form , what shall I do?

Here is a sample of the code for the screenshot

```
MenuStrip1.Hide()
    Dim bmpScreenshot As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    ' Create a graphics object from the bitmap  
    Dim gfxScreenshot As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot)
    ' Take a screenshot of the entire Form1  
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y, 0, 0, Me.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    ' Save the screenshot  
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Image files (*.PNG)|*.PNG|(*.JPG*)|*.JPG*"
    bmpScreenshot.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    MenuStrip1.Show()
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [PictureBox.DrawToBitmap()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx)?

Comment: @Idle_Mind i tried the bitmap thing , but all what i got was inaccurate results , all what i want is to export 2 pictureboxes as 1 picturebox , instead of being 2 pictureboxes . their locations will be the same just like a screenshot but i want to make sure it covers all the picture even the part not visible in the screen ( needs to scroll to see it) *sorry for my bad english*

Comment: Well...are the PictureBoxes side by side, or one above the other?  Do they have the same dimensions?  We can't see how you got "inaccurate" results unless you post a description and/or a screenshot to demonstrate....

Comment: Maybe set the picturebox to autosize and then get the height and width of it. Then resize the form accordingly before taking the screenshot?

Comment: nop , sometimes the height of the pic is too long that it won't fit in the screen even if i resized the form , that's the main problem i faced when i tried to use the screenshot solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what it might look like with PictureBox1 as the "background" and PictureBox2 as a smaller image "on top" of PictureBox1:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Image files (*.PNG)|*.PNG|(*.JPG*)|*.JPG*"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image.Width, PictureBox1.Image.Height)
        Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            G.Clear(Color.Black)
            G.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, New Point(0, 0))
            G.DrawImage(PictureBox2.Image, PictureBox2.Location)
        End Using
        Select Case System.IO.Path.GetExtension(SaveFileDialog1.FileName).ToUpper
            Case ".PNG"
                bmp.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            Case ".JPG"
                bmp.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort unfortunately that wasn't what i was looking for , i will explain what i want hoping i am quiet understandable  , there is a picture for object 1 , and object 2 , object 1 is the background image , object 2 is the moving picture , the user will set the location of object 2 on the background image after he does that i want to create a new picture that is like a screenshot for the existing state of object 1 and object 2 , but the problem is that screenshot won't work in some cases is there another way ? thanks and i hope i wasn't so complicated

Comment: No problem at all.  How are you moving object 2?  It sounds like it would be very similar to what I've posted already using two calls to DrawImage().

Comment: that won't be the problem , i just need the merging part , that's the point i am stuck in

Comment: So is object 2 a picturebox as well (and it is "on top" of the other one)?  How do you move object 2?